# How to populate tables with standard records in TYPO3 flow?

Tags: typo3, functional-testing, typo3-flow

I am trying to learn TYPO3 flow. And I want to develop an application which needs language models. I only need 4 of them (en, fr, de, es). So I've created a language model, but how should I populate the table with the 4 records? With migrations? They are only for schema updates, aren't they? What about my functional test, I need them in there too.

I dont want to add them manually, because I would have to do it on every server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Implement a command controller "setup" where you do all initial operations

so you can setup your package e.g. by ./flow setup:initDB